# Read data from text file into cell array

Tags: matlab

I have multiple text files that contain data in this format

File1.txt

```
subID    imageCondition  trial   textItem    imageFile   response    RT
Participant003   images  7   Is there a refrigerator?    07_targetPresent-refrigerator.jpg   z   1.436971
Participant003   images  6   Is there an oven mitt?  06_targetPresent-ovenmitt.jpg   z   0.519301
Participant003   images  1   Is there a toaster?     01_targetAbsent-toaster.jpg     m   1.110664
Participant003   images  3   Is there a wine bottle?     03_targetAbsent-winebottle.jpg  m   1.278945
Participant003   images  2   Is there a kettle?  02_targetAbsent-kettle.jpg  z   2.672123
Participant003   images  5   Is there a blender?     05_targetPresent-blender.jpg    m   2.633802
Participant003   images  8   Is there a bucket?  08_targetPresent-bucket.jpg     m   2.596154
Participant003   images  4   Is there a surf board?  04_targetAbsent-surfboard.jpg   m   1.072850
```

File2.txt

```
subID    imageCondition  trial   textItem    imageFile   response    RT
Participant005   images  1   Is there a toaster?     01_targetAbsent-toaster.jpg         0.000000
Participant005   images  2   Is there a kettle?  02_targetAbsent-kettle.jpg  m   8.213927
Participant005   images  6   Is there an oven mitt?  06_targetPresent-ovenmitt.jpg   z   3.569293
Participant005   images  4   Is there a surf board?  04_targetAbsent-surfboard.jpg       0.000000
Participant005   images  3   Is there a wine bottle?     03_targetAbsent-winebottle.jpg  m   8.538699
Participant005   images  7   Is there a refrigerator?    07_targetPresent-refrigerator.jpg   z   0.857319
Participant005   images  5   Is there a blender?     05_targetPresent-blender.jpg        0.000000
Participant005   images  8   Is there a bucket?  08_targetPresent-bucket.jpg     z   1.967220
```

I want to be able to read this data into a cell array so that I can individually access the values that are present in it.

I have the following code that I use to read the data but it's not helping because I am not able to store the data in a way so that I can access the individual values. For example I want all the values from the 'trial' or 'response' column.

```
function content = load_data(fileName)
fid = fopen(fileName,'r')
if fid > 0
   line_no =1;
   oneline{line_no} = fgetl(fid);
   while ischar(oneline{line_no})
      line_no = line_no +1;
      oneline{line_no} = fgetl(fid);
   endwhile
   fclose(fid)
   content = oneline;
endif
endfunction


for i= 1:size(txtFiles,2)
   data{i} = load_data(txtFiles{1,i});
end

for i=1:1:length(data)
   dataMat = cell2mat(data(i));
   for j=1:1:length(dataMat)
      line = dataMat{1,j};
      % Here I'm only able to fetch lines of data as strings that are separated by more than one space characters, making it more difficult access the required data 
   endfor            
endfor
```

What I'm looking for is a way to read this data from a text file into a cell array or a matrix so that I can easily access the required values but I am restricted to using the traditional methods of importing data from text file. Or if I could just get help with parsing the data in a way I can access what is required.

> Note: There are multiple text files like these. Also It'd be a great help if you can show how to access values in individual columns e.g. 'response' column.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? Sounds like the new `readtable` function might be right up your alley.

Comment: Hi @AndrewJanke , I'm using Matlab online so it must have the latest version but I think I maybe restricted to not use the new `readtable` function as this problem is from an assignment and the `readtable` was not yet taught to us.

Comment: can you use the `uimport` function? (simply drag&drop the file to the command window -- but I don't know if this works with MATLAB online). This should open a GUI, that helps you to configure the import and than you can let MATLAB generate an import functions with all your settings

Comment: Hi @max, I can't use the uimport function. Is there a way to do what I want using the code I have used to import the data from the text file? I know it might require a lot of effort parsing the data but I think I'm short of options :(

Comment: Unfortunately my hands are forced to use the traditional methods of importing data from text file.

Comment: Have you tried importdata?  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easy to do with something like strsplit to split the data based on spaces; except your textItem field has spaces in it. So I would suggest using regular expressions. Using [named tokens](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) is a convenient way to organize the results when you're looking for several separate pieces at a time. I realize that if you're not familiar with regular expressions, it's a tough thing to jump into. Check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for information and a very useful online tool for testing your regular expression. See [this specific example](https://regex101.com/r/oIhre6/1) on regex101. That said, here's my answer which works on your data:

```
text = fileread(filename);
data = regexp(data,'^(?<subID>\w+)\s+(?<imageCondition>\w+)\s+(?<trial>\d+)\s+(?<textItem>.*?\?)\s+(?<imageFile>[-\.\w]+)\s+(?<response>\w)\s+(?<RT>[\d\.]+)','names','lineanchors')
```

Or you could turn it into a table:

```
dataTable = struct2table(data)
```

Result looks like:

```
      subID           imageCondition    trial              textItem                            imageFile                  response         RT     
__________________    ______________    _____    ____________________________    _____________________________________    ________    ____________

{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'7'}    {'Is there a refrigerator?'}    {'07_targetPresent-refrigerator.jpg'}     {'z'}      {'1.436971'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'6'}    {'Is there an oven mitt?'  }    {'06_targetPresent-ovenmitt.jpg'    }     {'z'}      {'0.519301'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'1'}    {'Is there a toaster?'     }    {'01_targetAbsent-toaster.jpg'      }     {'m'}      {'1.110664'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'3'}    {'Is there a wine bottle?' }    {'03_targetAbsent-winebottle.jpg'   }     {'m'}      {'1.278945'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'2'}    {'Is there a kettle?'      }    {'02_targetAbsent-kettle.jpg'       }     {'z'}      {'2.672123'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'5'}    {'Is there a blender?'     }    {'05_targetPresent-blender.jpg'     }     {'m'}      {'2.633802'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'8'}    {'Is there a bucket?'      }    {'08_targetPresent-bucket.jpg'      }     {'m'}      {'2.596154'}
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}      {'4'}    {'Is there a surf board?'  }    {'04_targetAbsent-surfboard.jpg'    }     {'m'}      {'1.072850'}
```

If you want to turn the numeric fields into numbers:

```
dataTable.trial = str2double(dataTable.trial);
dataTable.RT = str2double(dataTable.RT);
```

Which then gives:

```
      subID           imageCondition    trial              textItem                            imageFile                  response      RT  
__________________    ______________    _____    ____________________________    _____________________________________    ________    ______

{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        7      {'Is there a refrigerator?'}    {'07_targetPresent-refrigerator.jpg'}     {'z'}       1.437
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        6      {'Is there an oven mitt?'  }    {'06_targetPresent-ovenmitt.jpg'    }     {'z'}      0.5193
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        1      {'Is there a toaster?'     }    {'01_targetAbsent-toaster.jpg'      }     {'m'}      1.1107
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        3      {'Is there a wine bottle?' }    {'03_targetAbsent-winebottle.jpg'   }     {'m'}      1.2789
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        2      {'Is there a kettle?'      }    {'02_targetAbsent-kettle.jpg'       }     {'z'}      2.6721
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        5      {'Is there a blender?'     }    {'05_targetPresent-blender.jpg'     }     {'m'}      2.6338
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        8      {'Is there a bucket?'      }    {'08_targetPresent-bucket.jpg'      }     {'m'}      2.5962
{'Participant003'}      {'images'}        4      {'Is there a surf board?'  }    {'04_targetAbsent-surfboard.jpg'    }     {'m'}      1.0729
```

You also asked how to access it. Get the third "response" from the table:

```
dataTable.response{3}
```

Or from the structure:

```
data(3).response
```

Comment: Mike, your solution works perfectly but there's a slight bit of problem with some of the files. In few of the text files the value for response column is empty in some of the rows and that messes up the data in the table. I'm sorry I didn't post a file with that kind of exception. Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: I have just added an example of that file as an edit to my question. You can find it under File2.txt

Comment: I got it to work. I handled it with a small change in your proposed regexp. `(?<response>\w|\W)` Thank you very much for the answer.